# Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate function

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I have an azure function with below structure

Startup.cs

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Edos.DatabaseInit.Startup))]
namespace Edos.DatabaseInit;
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection collection)
    {
        

        collection.AddInfrastructure(this.configuration);
    }
}
```

Function1.cs

```
public class CosmosInit
{
    private readonly IMessagingService _messagingService;


    public CosmosInit(IMessagingService messagingService)
    {
        _messagingService = messagingService;
        
    }
    [FunctionName("CosmosInit")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {

        await _messagingService.PushToTopic("topic", "message");
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        return new OkObjectResult("");
    }
}
```

**And in infrastructure project**

*DependencyInjection.cs*

```
public static class DependencyInjection
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {

        var serviceBusConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBusConnectionString");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceBusConnectionString))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Please specify a valid ServiceBusConnectionString in the Azure Functions Settings or your local.settings.json file.");
        }

        //using AMQP as transport
        services.AddSingleton((s) => {
            return new ServiceBusClient(serviceBusConnectionString, new ServiceBusClientOptions() { TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets });
        });
        services.AddScoped<IMessagingService, MessagingService>();
        return services;
    }
}
```

*MessagingService.cs*

```
public class MessagingService: IMessagingService
{
    private readonly ServiceBusClient _serviceBusClient;

    public MessagingService(ServiceBusClient serviceBusClient)
    {
        _serviceBusClient = serviceBusClient;
    }
    // the sender used to publish messages to the topic
    
    public async Task<int> PushToTopic(string topic, string serviceMessage)
    {
        var sender = _serviceBusClient.CreateSender(topic);
        var message = new ServiceBusMessage(serviceMessage);
        await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);
        return 1;

    }
}
```

*IMessagingService.cs*

```
public interface IMessagingService
{
    Task<int> PushToTopic(string topic, string message);
}
```

As you can see I have the service bus client is injected into the MessageService.

And in the Function startup as well I have added the infrastructure collection.

Thus I am getting the PushToTopic method within the function as well.

But whenever I am trying to call the function it triggers the below error

> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions: Unable to resolve service for type 'DataFoundation.Infrastructure.Services.IMessagingService' while attempting to activate 'DatabaseInit.CosmosInit'.

Please share your comments.. It took my whole day..

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I think your Startup class needs to extend FunctionStartup for it to work properly.

Comment: What hosting mechanism (in process or isolated) are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Your `Startup` class should extend `FunctionsStartup` class. And you should be overriding its `Configure` method instead.
Like so:

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Edos.DatabaseInit.Startup))]
namespace Edos.DatabaseInit;
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
  public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
  {
    var configuration = builder.GetContext().Configuration;
    builder.Services.AddInfrastructure(configuration);
  }
}
```